# Java Hibernate Warnings

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Начал изучать Hibernate, решил разобраться на практике с помощью примера с данного сайта [devcolibri](http://devcolibri.com/1394).
Проект у меня компилируется, и отлично выполняется, данные в базу данных успешно заносятся, но есть один вопрос, который меня смущает: после добавления в `hibernate.cfg.xml` строки `<mapping resource="com/devcolibri/User.hbm.xml"></mapping>`, в файле `User.hmb.xml` появляются warnings в строках, связанных с таблицей.
[image: Ошибки]
Если на любой нажать Alt+Enter, то предлагается решение в виде `Assign Data Sources`, но перейдя в предложенное окно, я не вижу способа решения проблемы.
[image: Решение]
Можно ли как-то избавиться от warnins, или единственным выходом является просто смириться с их присутствием?
`User.hbm.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.devcolibri.entity.User" table="user" catalog="test">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="USER_ID" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="FIRST_NAME" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="LAST_NAME" length="20" not-null="true" unique="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">hunter999love</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="com/devcolibri/User.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы вставите код текстом, а не скринштом.

Comment: Если не составит труда, то просьба перейти по ссылке на сайт, там есть весь код, просто у меня почему-то не хочет нормально вставляться сюда кусок кода, обрезается.

Comment: Вставьте код, выделите и нажмите кнопку `{ }` в редакторе.

Comment: Благодарю за пояснение.

Comment: IDEA, в том числе, умеет проверять всякие такие штуки типа наличия колонок в БД. Т.к. у нее где-то включен этот inspection и она действительно не может их найти (у нее нет data source'ов), то она подсвечивает их красным. Для избавления от этого проще всего установить инспекцию файла на уровне синтаксиса (иконка инспектора в правом нижнем углу).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалось разобраться с данным вопросом. Для этого собственно надо было задать свой datasource. Для этого:

1. Щелкаем в правом верхнем углу на вкладку `Databases`, потом в этой вкладке нажимаем на зеленый плюс `New > Data Source > MySQL`.
2. В новом окне настраиваете вашу базу данных: вводите имя базы данных, а так же имя пользователя и пароль. После чего нажимаете `Test Connection`, если все удачно, то нажимаете `Apply` и `Ok`.
3. Потом нажимаете на строке с ошибкой `Alt+Enter`, выбираете `Assign Data Source`, и в новом окне выбираете настроенный вами ранее вариант.
4. После этого дожидаетесь, пока Idea перестроит проект, и радуетесь отсутствию ошибок.